# Cannot update last row on SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

```
public public udpateNoteInfo(String text){
    ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
    val.put(KEY_CONTENT5, text);        

    sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, val,"ORDER_BY("+KEY_ID+") DESC LIMIT 0,1",  new String[]{text});  
}
```

I try to update the last row of the KEY_CONTENT5 column in my SQLite, but it's error.
I guess its mistake at `"ORDER_BY("+KEY_ID+") DESC LIMIT 0,1"` but I don't know how to make it correct. Please tell me if you know that. Thank you.

```
ERROR:
09-05 11:47:54.769 E/Database( 4386): Error updating note=Test using UPDATE PERSONAL_TABLE SET note=? WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM PERSONAL_TABLE)
```

**Activity class:**

```
public void updateNote(String txt) {
        mySQLiteAdapter = new PersonalSQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
        if (cursor != null) {   
            mySQLiteAdapter.udpateNoteInfo(txt);
        }
        mySQLiteAdapter.close();
    }
```

**SQLiteAdapter class (not activity):**

```
public void udpateNoteInfo(String text) {
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(KEY_CONTENT5, text);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, val, KEY_ID + " = (SELECT max("
                + KEY_ID + ") FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + ")",
                new String[] { text });

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put an order by in an update.
You can try something like this:
WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM TABLE) if you want to update the last id, assuming your sequences aren't modified.

Comment: I try your suggestion like this : sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, val,"WHERE "+KEY_ID+" = (SELECT max("+KEY_ID+") FROM "+MYDATABASE_TABLE+")",  new String[]{text}); But it's still error.

Comment: Paste the error here, it might be connected to something else.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I put 'WHERE' out because it have double WHERE in logcat then I think its wrong. However, it's still error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please paste the entire logcat stack trace so we can see the actual exception. I assume that "Error updating..." is your own comment when you catch the exception. Make sure you log the exception by giving it as a param to the logcat:
Log.d("LOGTAG", "Error updating...", e);

Comment: Error Updating is not my comment, I run it on android phone and it show just that on aLogcat application. However, I edit my code above that hope you more understand it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void udpateNoteInfo(String text) {
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(KEY_CONTENT5, text);
        sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, val, KEY_ID+" = (SELECT max("+KEY_ID+") FROM "+MYDATABASE_TABLE+")", null);
    }
```

My final answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the ID, and then, update this row... if your key_id values are not unique, you'll need to use your primary key column(s) instead of this one...

```
Cursor cLast = db.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, [KEY_ID], null, null, null, "ORDER_BY("+KEY_ID+") DESC", "LIMIT 0,1");
if (cLast.moveToFirst()) {
  long lastKey = cLast.getLong(0); // if it's not a long, use the appropriate getter
  sqLiteDatabase.update(MYDATABASE_TABLE, val, "WHERE KEY_ID=?", lastKey);
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? I pretty confuse with variables such as cLast and itemCursor are the same ? The parameter is not complete? What is lastKey doing, I think its never use after it was assigned. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to change some names/params... I just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE table set col = 1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)